# Base class "Object", lazy/smart or stupid?

Tags: c++, inheritance

What I'm wondering is: if having a base class, that every* other class inherits from is a good idea or not in C++. Basically, it has the same interface as C#'s Object, which is:

*except for straight interfaces and data structures

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() {}
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
    virtual Object* copy() const = 0;
    virtual void release() = 0;
private:
    // This operator overload calls toString() to print it out to the stream.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Object& object);
};
```

Is this a good thing to do, or am I better off just making seperate interfaces if I want the class to be copied, or converted to a string.

For example

```
class Copyable
{
public:
    virtual ~Copyable() {}
    virtual Copyable* copy() const = 0;
};
```

I'm not sure about this at all, and it's doing my head in. :(

Comment: `System.Object` isn't abstract - C# doesn't force you to implement `toString()` etc.

Comment: I often like having `Object` class such as this, is like having `void*` scattered throughout in your code. Everything can be converted into everything else, which harms static type-safety, if not anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it. Your `Object` forces each and every class to implement those pure virtual methods. What if you don't really need them?

C++ has multiple inheritance, so you can have a separate class for each purpose, and let the derived classes decide which traits do they need.

Having those virtual function also adds an overhead, as it adds a vptr to every instance of every class. Might not have a horrible effect, but it's not the C++ spirit IMO.

Lastely, C# and Java's `Object` have some useful methods because they have a lot more information on the type at runtime. This makes having a single root for all types reasonable. Some C++ frameworks have it as well (MFC's `CObject` comes to mind), but providing useful facilities at that level is not trivial in C++. You'll have to do more than just offer pure virtual methods - the major gain from having a single root is getting shared implementation via inheritance, not polymorphism. Using your `Object` in a polymorphic manner just breaks static typing, and in your case, you don't even get any code reuse.

Comment: Note that the actual C# and Java `Object` classes do not, in fact, require force every class to implement those methods. But other than that, good points.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart, sure, Java and C# provide default implementation to those methods. But that's possible because those language provide more type information at runtime. In C++, you can provide some default `toString` using `typeid(this).name()` (and possibly demangle the results), but you can't use RTTI to provide a default `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have common base class for all objects primarily for perf reasons, especially because of the VMT (virtual methods table). VMT is a pointer that is present in every object that has at least one virtual method. Authors of C++ wanted to support simple objects (with body consisting of one int for example). This is valid and reasonable goal.

Comment: virtual table is an implementation defined thing. Don't refer to it when explaining things in general

Comment: I can't but it's not specified by standard. So it's better to avoid referencing to things that are not specified by standard.

Comment: I always favor clarity and ease of explanation. Note that eran mentions `vptr` that is the same thing.

Comment: You can just mention that it's implementaion defined )

Answer (score 0):

This only works if enforced at the language level (as in Java.) In C++ you'd have to deal with non-Object objects anyway. There is no way to force libraries to inherit from `Object`. Once you instantiate anything from `std::`, you have a non-Object object in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a one size fits all answer.

Think through what benefits it is going to give you.
Now think through how much extra work it is going to cause e.g. multiple inheritance complications etc.

Generally doing this is going to be more work than not doing it so you need to make sure that it is going to give you a substantial benefit or you are wasting time.